explicit coordinate charts for Lie groups
In all the definitions of Lie groups $O(N), SO(N), U(N), SU(N)$ that I encountered their coordinate charts were defined implicitly - as slice charts from embedding into $GL(\mathbb{R}, N)$. For example, (without going into many details) $O(N)$ can be viewed as level set of the map $\Phi: GL(\mathbb{R}, N)\rightarrow \text{Mat}(\mathbb{R}, N)$ such that $\Phi(A)=A^tA$, making $O(N)$  embedded submanifold. But this approach doesn't provide any explicit coordinate charts on $O(N)$, which would be useful for computations.
So my question is the following: is there any explicit way to define coordinate charts on $O(N), SO(N), U(N), SU(N)$? May be for each group, there is some general approach?
It seems like for lower dimensional cases, like $SU(2), SO(2), U(1)$ we can use charts from famous diffeomorphisms $SU(2)\cong S^3, SO(2)\cong U(1)\cong S^1$, but my question still remains open even for $O(2), U(2)$.
Any links to literature will also be appreciated.

$O(2)$ isn't hard because it's a disjoint union of two circles.  But as a topologist [not a geometer] I've never needed hard coordinates.  (That is, someone more experienced might give you a good answer.)

@Randall Thanks! That makes sense. I need to analyse critical points of certain functions on these manifolds, so explicit coordinates are essential to me.

I don't believe there is an easy answer for you. You can certainly work with $U(2)$ locally as a circle bundle over $SU(2)$. How are you defining the functions?

@TedShifrin Actually, I am more interested in $SU(N), U(N)$, since I am physicist and I study certain quantum spaces. In particular, I try to analyse transition probability from one quantum state to another. To put it mathematically, this function is just a certain element of matrix $A\in U(N)$, but, since I need to analyse its critical points on $U(N)$ manifold, I need to know explicit coordinate charts.

Well, I'm confused. If you write $A=[a_{ij}]$, then unless $|a_{ij}|=1$, can't you always use $a_{ij}$ as one element of a local coordinate chart on your group?

@TedShifrin Can you, please, explain it in details? Because I thought that one can only use matrix elements as local coordinates only in case of $A\in GL(\mathbb{R}, n)$...

Work out $U(2)$ and $SU(2)$ explicitly. For $SU(2)$, we have elements $\begin{bmatrix} a&b\-\bar b&\bar a\end{bmatrix}$ with $a,b\in\Bbb C$ and $|a|^2+|b|^2=1$. So, unless $|a|=1$, $a$ is free to vary over a disk in $\Bbb C$ and then you can (locally) solve for $b$ on a circle of a given radius. You can do $U(2)$ similarly: If $|a_{11}|\ne 1$, then $a_{11}$ is free to vary over a disk, and the magnitudes of the remaining entries are determined by it, along with one further constraint. But my original claim will hold true for any $N$.

Before looking for explicit charts, you should ask yourself if you really need these. What is the actual motivation?

@Moishe Look four comments up.

@TedShifrin: This should be an edit, not a comment. Besides, for finding critical points, one can use Lagrange multipliers, without any explicit charts. My guess is that OP is simply looking at a wring place

I agree. I was focusing on the local coordinates question, which turns out to be a red herring. For the optimization question, one clearly should be doing Lagrange multipliers.

Can you use the expotential map?
